# Does a female breast shape predict personality?

Tags: psychology, sexuality

This has been claimed all over Russian language newsfeeds, I think originating [at this link](http://ladyportal.info/it_and_it/psychology/19545-temperament-zhenschiny-zavisit-ot-formy-grudi.html):

> Обратив внимание на форму женской груди, каждый мужчина может предсказать, что ожидает его, если он свяжет свою жизнь с той или иной женщиной.
>   К такому выводу пришли немецкие ученые, проведя специальные исследования в этой области.
>
> **By noting the shape of the female breast, every man can predict** what awaits him if he will tie his life to a specific woman (*the article context means, her personality*)
>   **This is the conclusion the German scientists, conducting special studies in this area**.

The article goes on matching the breast shape to personality - I'm a bit hesitant to post specific details in the interests of keeping the site PG-13.

It didn't bother specifying what the study being described is.

Answer (score 16):

The article only mentions unnamed "German scientists" for its claim. The only person named by name is Karen Weatherby, and she is used to support a different claim (looking at breasts is healthy). This claim - and the existence of Weatherby - has been [debunked](http://urbanlegends.about.com/od/medical/a/ogling_breasts.htm).

There is one German scientist [claiming this](http://www.frauenzimmer.de/cms/leben-genuss/2011-06/galerie/charakter-form-brueste.html), Ruediger Dahlke, in his book "Der Körper als Spiegel der Seele" (The body as mirror of the soul). He is an esoteric scientist who believes in [inedia](https://books.google.de/books?id=ngU-L9IXgukC&printsec=frontcover&dq=lichtnahrung+dahlke&hl=de&sa=X&ei=U0FIU5PYN7CM4gSrk4D4AQ#v=onepage&q=lichtnahrung%20dahlke&f=false). He doesn't seem to have done any actual studies.

The only other source for this claim is a [German tabloid (NSFW)](http://www.bz-berlin.de/artikel-archiv/brueste-verraten-ihre-liebes-qualitaeten), quoting Italian sexologist Piero Lorenzoni. Most of the English speaking articles about this topic seem to have gotten their claims from him as well. He does not seem to have done any studies, and does not provide any sources for his claim.

There haven't been any real studies on breast shape and personality that I could find - which isn't surprising -, but the fact that the article doesn't name the scientists, and also contains already debunked information is a hint at its quality, and the fact that the only scientist - apart from a sexologist who does not name any sources - who seems to support this idea has a lot of other pesudo-sicentific ideas, strongly suggest that this idea is not based on any current scientific evidence.